# SQL data cleansing

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wanted to see if someone can help me with some data cleansing:

1. I need to identify columns that have at least 5 numbers in a row. There is other data in the column
2. I need to identify columns that have exactly nine numbers in a row AND have "(" one space to the right.  There is other data around this combination

example - XXXXXXXXX (

I will apply this logic to a case expression.

Comment: Downvote reason?

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis as I'm sure you know the official guidance from SO is **not** to provide a reason for a downvote, hovering your mouse over the downvote button gives you the reasons. (And no it wasn't me).

Comment: Lack of sample data and expected result is a good reason.

Comment: Make it easy, and possible, to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: Thanks I got the first one resolved.  The second one doesn't seem to be working with the (.   real example: 125369875 (

Answer (score 0):

```
  select *
  from your_table 
  where (
    your_column like '%11111$' 
        or your_column like '%22222%' 
        or your_column like '%33333%'
        or your_column like '%44444%'
        or your_column like '%55555%'
        or your_column like '%66666%'
        or your_column like '%77777%'
        or your_column like '%88888%'
        or your_column like '%99999%'
        or your_column like '%00000%'
   or your_column like '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] ('
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that no matter what you do it is a scan of the table

This needs to be a simple one-time pass program and on a backup image of the database

You can also use REPLACE in a wacky way to eliminate letters and put it all into a temp table, then just hammer on it .

I do something different.

I find position markers according to how the string was built, and apply meaningful name variables such as

First_left_paren_pos , third_space_pos, and other things like that, then, if your number is supposed to be between two markers, just do a substring on that column between those markers

In the real case, I will find that " (" at the end